# Terraform VMSS CustomScriptExtension - How to point to a script in storage account blob?

Tags: azure, terraform

I know how to create a Windows VMSS [CustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) using an inline script via terraform [azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_scale_set_extension.html) resource but not quite sure how to create an extension which can point to a script in the storage account.

I think it would be in the `settings` parameter but not sure how.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "vmss" {
  name                         = "userdata"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                         = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version         = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      ## This is what I am not sure of
      "script": "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<my_script>.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Comment: Try this script: settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "scriptUri": "https://cvdvd.blob.core.windows.net/test/VMSS.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File VMSS.ps1"
    }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}, Same is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

> how to create an extension which can point to a script in the storage account.

To reference a script in a storage account for the `CustomScriptExtension` in an `Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set`  using `Terraform`

Here is the updated `Terraform` script:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "venkat-vmss"
  resource_group_name = "venkattests-resources"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "vmss_extension" {
  name                 = "customScript"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = data.azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "scriptUri": "https://vmssvm.blob.core.windows.net/venkat/VMSS.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File VMSS.ps1"
    }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

The settings block in terraform contains the **scriptUri** parameter, which specifies the `URI` of the powershell script in the `Azure storage account`. The protected_settings block contains the **commandToExecute** parameter.

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]